# NavigationManager issue

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to use NavigationManager.NavigateTo("...") in Blazor WebAssembly C# and according to many sources it's correct, but IDE shows mistake and says that for non-static methods I need to create an instance of this class. Would appreciate any ideas about solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject an instance of the NavigationManager

`@inject NavigationManager navigationManager`

Then you can use it

`navigationManager.NavigateTo("...")`